# Is studying complete mitochondrial genome need biological lab work?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna, mitochondria

The research **complete mitochondrial genome study** done on species:

1. [Juema pig Sus scrofa (Suina: Suidae) from southern Gansu](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26359921)
2. [red rainbowfish](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26359678)
3. [speckled dace, Rhinichthys osculus](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26359550)
4. [white char Salvelinus albus (Salmoniformes, Salmonidae)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26358825)
5. [Himalayan honey bee, Apis laboriosa](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26360118)

Did they need to do any work in biological laboratory?

More specifically, Are they related to bioinformatics completely?

Most of them just wrote length in bp (base pair), percentage of ATGC and several combinations of them and some special behavior. These seemed to me as expressing some statistics.

So, how could it be a research work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All papers you mentioned have involved biological lab work. They all have sequences specific mitochondrial genome and then have analyzed it with the help of bioinformatics. Sequencing genome requires lot of bench work (wet work or "biological lab work"). Even [one](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26360118) of them have mentioned it in abstract itself.

> The complete mitochondrial genome of Himalayan bee Apis laboriosa, from Mizoram, India, has been sequenced using Illumina NextSeq500 platform and analysed.

Comment: Yes, obviously there should some biological lab work. but is it possible to do this types of thesis without doing the biological lab work practically? say collecting the lab work data from any open source gene bank or something. You know, a lot of bioinformatics thesis could be done without doing any biological lab work. can it be done that way? (Sorry for my bad English. I asked one question here, but several questions appearing to make you understand the question)

Comment: @manetsus **Someone** needs to do the lab work to generate the data for analysis by bioinformatics. That's not always the person doing the analysis, but even then they must have a very strong understanding of biology in order to create relevant conclusions. The best way to learn biology is by *doing*.

Comment: @MattDMo I fully agree with you. but my question is the one who just doing analysis on the basis of lab work available on the internet is producing knowledge or not?

Comment: @manetsus if you are making novel insights into biological phenomena, then of course you are producing knowledge, regardless of whether you have a pipettor or a computer mouse in your hand. Just look at the fields of mathematics and theoretical physics - a lot of work is done without ever being able to do experiments at all.

Comment: @manetsus, Yes that is possible. You can join any theory, bioinformatics, systems biology or computational biology lab. These don't required wet work. These fields are also in demand now a days.